# Может ли выражение "один черт" быть вводным?

Tags: вводные-слова

Например:"Чего же, спрашивается, бояться, если, один черт, конец пришел?"

Comment: Здесь больше "чёрт возьми" подходит в качестве вводного. С "одним чёртом" получается иная (не вводная) конструкция: _Чего же, спрашивается, бояться, если один чёрт - конец пришел?_

Comment: Здесь что-то вроде междометия с последующим его объяснением, а вводные слова обычно относятся ко всему высказыванию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Чего же, спрашивается, бояться, если, **один черт**, конец пришел?*

1) Из словаря:  ***Один чёрт***. Неодобр. **Одно и то же, всё равно, одинаково.**

2) Выражение ***один черт*** может выполнять различные синтаксические функции, в том числе **может быть вводным словосочетанием**.

В этом случае оно обособляется, не входит в структуру предложения (не является членом предложения) и имеет модальное оценочное значение. При обособлении может использоваться тире.

**Примеры:**

Ладно, ― перебил он меня, ― Алексеев так Алексеев, **один черт**. [Виктор Некрасов. (1983)]

**Один черт**, я по ночам почти не сплю, а зараз и вовсе. [М. А. Шолохов. (1959)]

Я вздохнул и начал Сашку в чувства приводить. Толкал, пихал, **один черт** ― не разбудил.  [Алексей Моторов. (2013)]

3) Но это выражение **не обособляется**, если является **членом предложения:**

Хочешь ― оставайся, хочешь ― нет, мне **один черт** (= всё равно). [Юрий Трифонов. Утоление жажды (1959-1962)]

В этом предложении оборот входит в состав сказуемого.

Comment: В начале и в конце предложения - очевидно, что "один чёрт" может быть вводным выражением и в большинстве случаев таковым является. А здесь (на мой взгляд) - по функции и требуемой пунктуации ближе к примеру из 2013 года, хотя в нём и более явная привязка к отдельным членам предложения (у нас - к подразумеваемой ситуации: "если /выходит так, что/ один чёрт").

Comment: Примеры: ...дорогу-то, один черт, знаю не хуже коренника. [Алексей Иванов. (1982)]Я и овса даю им в полную меру, а они, один черт, и не поглядывают на кобылок. [М. А. Шолохов. (1959)] А вообще говоря, это выражение  значение-то  имеет постоянное ( =всё равно, одинаково),  а вводным оно становится тогда, когда перестает вписываться в структуру предложения. Вот и в заданном предложении оборот занимает позицию, требующую обособления, так как никак не сочетается со словом "конец".

Comment: Спасибо. Да, здесь "оно" может быть только вводным - нет связи по управлению с предшествующим текстом. Вот если бы в шолоховском фрагменте было "а им один чёрт (-) ", было бы похоже на наш случай.

Comment: @Sharon Обратите внимание на Ваше предложение. _**Выражение** один черт может выполнять различные синтаксические функции, в том числе может быть вводным **словом**._ Мне кажется, что последнее слово надо убрать (выражение не может быть словом). А в остальном — как у прекрасной маркизы.